# Is it possible to call AWS Step Functions from AWS JavaScript v3 SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I posted [this question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=992628#992628) on the forums back in August requesting when the V3 JavaScript API would add support to AWS Step Functions as it is in the V2 SDK. I haven't heard anything on that thread.

Is there an alternate solution that someone has which I can migrate away from the V2 SDK?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently there is support for invoking Step Functions from AWS V3 Javascript sdk.

For standard invocation we can use [`StartExecutionCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sfn/classes/startexecutioncommand.html), or we can use [`StartSyncExecutionCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sfn/classes/startsyncexecutioncommand.html) for Synchronous Express step functions.

Here is an example for a standard invocation using Node.js:

```
const { SFNClient, StartExecutionCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sfn");

const client = new SFNClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });

async function invoke(executionName, arn, input) {
    const command = new StartExecutionCommand({
        input: JSON.stringify(input),
        name: executionName,
        stateMachineArn: arn
    });
    return await client.send(command);
}

(async () => {
    console.log(await invoke('execution123', '' +
        'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:stateMachine:HelloWorld',
        {fistName: 'test'}));
})();
```

Comment: Oh, damn; it's now called `sfn`. I was looking for `state` or `machine` for the clients and couldn't find it. TBH I think the V2 API was much easier to find things than the V3 one.